# LG G5 Clear individual app cache when using "Home with app drawer"

Tags: application-manager, app-data, lg-g5

I recently purchased an LG G5 phone. I am using the "Home with app drawer" home mode because I like having the app drawer.

I need to clear the data cache for an individual app. I know that you normally access this via the App Manager, selecting the desired app, and then clicking the "Clear Cache" button. However, when I go into Settings on my phone, I can't find "App Manager". The closest that I can find in Settings is "Apps". This screen lists all of my apps, but when I select one, there is no "Clear Cache" button.

How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use "Home with app drawer" but I think it's the same.

Go to Settings > Apps as you've already found. Then tap `Storage`. You'll see a new screen with the various figures and `Clear data` and `Clear cache` buttons.